# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY ISSUE

Tags: node.js, angular, ngx-bootstrap

I have been trying to install the ngx bootstrap from [https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started]

by entering the command: npm install ngx-bootstrap --save

but the result is this:

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.4.10
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.4.10
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.4.10
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@2.4.10
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY jquery@1.9.1 - 3
+-- ngx-bootstrap@2.0.0-beta.9
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY popper.js@^1.12.3
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@2.0.10

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.5 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.5 requires a peer of @angular/common@^4.0.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.5 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^4.0.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none was installed.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.12.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN ngx-bootstrap@2.0.0-beta.9 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=4.3.0 || >5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ngx-bootstrap@2.0.0-beta.9 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@>=4.3.0 || >5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ngx-bootstrap@2.0.0-beta.9 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=4.3.0 || >5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ngx-bootstrap@2.0.0-beta.9 requires a peer of @angular/forms@>=4.3.0 || >5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ngx-bootstrap@2.0.0-beta.9 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.3.0 but none was installed.
```

I do not understand what's happening.

I am fairly new to Angular 2 and the relevant technologies. Would appreciate your help ! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

hello you need to install your perDependencies, if you install a package that depends on specific versions of other packages, If it didn't find the correct  version of package then "Peer dependency" is unmet, try this:

```
npm install -g npm-install-peers

npm-install-peers
```

this will install peerDependencies